# $Y \subset X$ noetherian schemes, $\mathcal{F} \in Y-\mathbf{Mod}$. When $H^i(Y,\mathcal{F})=H^i(X,\mathcal{F})?$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, sheaf-cohomology

Let $Y \subset X$ noetherian schemes, $\mathcal{F} \in Y-\mathbf{Mod}$. When $H^i(Y,\mathcal{F})=H^i(X,\mathcal{F})?$ Is it true in general? Is it true in case when $\mathcal{F}$ coherent? The question emerged because Hartshorne proof of III.7.4:

[image]

I think he uses fact $H^{N-i}(P,\mathcal{O}_X(-q))=H^{N-i}(X,\mathcal{O}_X(-q))$. But for me its not obvious why its true.

Comment: It is true when $Y\subset X$ is closed. The thing is $H^k(X,\mathcal{F})$ is a shorthand for $H^k(X,i_*\mathcal{F})$ where $i:Y\rightarrow X$ is the inclusion. Now use the fact that $i_*$ is an exact functor which preserve injectives and that $H^0(X,i_*\mathcal{F})=H^0(Y,\mathcal{F})$ (which follows immediately from the definition of $i_*$).